# fopen: failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Tags: php, fopen

I have the following piece of code (`$settings` is some data):

```
$file = fopen("D:\\this\\is\\the\\path.php", "w");
fwrite($file, $settings);
fclose($file);
```

And I get this error:

```
fopen(D:\this\is\the\path.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

I already tried to modify the path:

```
D:\this\is\the\path.php
D:/this/is/the/path.php
```

nothing works, and I'm sure the path is correct and the code is correct!
The strange this is, that it works (if the file doesn't exist) with mode `x` (create file and write)

But if the file exists I can't overwrite it in mode `w` for some reason.

I'm using a Windows system.

I already checked many other answers but mine just doesn't work, even if I do everything correct from the other answers.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php - ```Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.```

Your script is unable to open that file for writing.

Comment: Why should the script be unable? The user has the correct permissions.. I'm 100% sure the path is correct. If I add a wrong path it will say the file was not found

Comment: It's usually permissions, but I can't say for certain. To verify that it is a permission issue you could run your script from a shell that you "run as administrator"

Comment: _"The strange this is, that it works (if the file doesn't exist) with mode x (create file and write) But if the file exists I can't overwrite it in mode w for some reason."_ - sounds like some kind of file lock might still be in place, when you are trying to write to the file again. Since you named the file .php - are you including this file somewhere in your application "at the same time" somehow, is it maybe even your general settings file for the whole project, so that other concurrent requests might cause a lock situation?

Comment: There is no file lock, I can edit it with the notepad. I will try to run the script with shell.

Comment: I found the problem.. I'm running xcache. I disabled it and it worked.. Not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Try using `realpath`, like this:

```
$file = fopen( realpath( "D:\\this\\is\\the\\path.php" ), "w" );
```